# Workbox service-worker won't work on second html

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Hey everyone i'm new to Workbox and iv'e been using the CLI to generate a SW with precaching, i have two html files index and restaurant_details my issue is that when i go offline to access index page that holds all of the restaurant reviews i have and i can click to see the details, now that page works fine and all the cached files are working great but when i try to view details of a restaurant that i already visited and that has its own files cached the SW disappears completely and it's cache with it.

The odd thing is that if i plug out my Ethernet cable and see if the restaurant details work fine they do and the SW stays on and the cached files get retrieved and it all works fine, could someone explain to me why that would happen and what i can do to fix it.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: *the SW disappears completely* sounds like an issue with the scope of your service worker; see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#scope_and_control